# how to use index find element for android appium

Tags: xpath, appium, robotframework

I am testing my Android application using Appium + robot framework.

because an android screen that doesn't have ids for these elements.
So I used the xpath to find the elements then I can find the index[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjg3l.png) success but index[3] can't find.

[This is how the screen looks like in UI Automator Viewer:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjg3l.png)

[image: This is how the screen looks like in UI Automator Viewer]

my xpath:

```
input text    xpath=//android.widget.EditText[1]   xxx
input text    xpath=//android.widget.EditText[3]   xxx
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: add the error message:  20190211 17:59:29.598 :  FAIL : ValueError: Element locator 'xpath=//android.widget.EditText[3]' did not match any elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
xpath=//android.widget.EditText[2]
```

The xpath reads "find all `android.wdiget.EditText` and return the n-th matching node - in your case, the target one is the 2nd in the nodeset; you've mistaken the condition as the n-th chield of the parent node.
Plus, the position in xpath start from 1, not 0.

Comment: I suspect that the correct answer is either `//android.widget.EditText[@index='3']` or `//android.widget.EditText[@index=3]`  Appium's native app heirarchy uses index values in a strange way (as you can see) and while I don't often use the index attribute, I am fairly certain it expects the value to be in quotes.

Comment: I tried to use 
xpath=//android.widget.EditText[@index=3] 
xpath=//android.widget.EditText[@index='3']

but both of these xpth also can't work.....

Comment: So why would you use that. As given in that xpath, `index` must be a node's actual property - and it does not look to be so. Try with the one in my answer, `//android.widget.EditText[2]` @brianpai

Comment: I used the "xpath=//android.widget.EditText[2]", it also can't work.

Error message:
FAIL : ValueError: Element locator 'xpath=//android.widget.EditText[2]' did not match any elements.  @TodorMinakov

Comment: Anybody got solution on this? I am also facing this issue